# How create simulation in .NET WinForm app using timer?

Tags: .net, winforms, timer

Using .NET WinForms, I want to create a prototype simulation wherein a progress bar fills slowly and unevenly based on my programmatic control (I'm going to have two of them and want to make it look like a "race" where they keep passing each other on their way to 100%).

I'm using the Timer class but not correctly, obviously:

Private Sub RunSimulation()

```
Dim myTimer As New Timer()

deliveredUltraProgressBar.Value = 0
myTimer.Interval = 5000   '5 seconds.
myTimer.Start()
deliveredUltraProgressBar.Value = 12
myTimer.Start()
deliveredUltraProgressBar.Value = 28
myTimer.Start()
deliveredUltraProgressBar.Value = 34
'Etc

myTimer.Stop()
```

End Sub

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The timer raises events so you need to handle the events:

```
AddHandler myTimer.Tick, AddressOf Timer_Tick
myTimer.Start()

Public Sub Timer_Tick(sender as Object, e as EventArgs)

    deliveredUltraProgressBar.Value += 5

End Sub
```

You might need to fiddle a bit with the syntax as I just typed this here in SO, but this is the idea.